# Smallest value of $abcd$ for positive integers $a,b,c,d$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came across this problem and haven't been able to solve it. The question goes like:

For distinct positive integers $a,b,c,d$ that satisfy the equation $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$. what is the smallest possible value for $abcd$.

I tried adding some small integer squares and found that $1^2+8^2= 65  = 4^2+7^2$ so $1 × 8 × 7 × 4=224 $ is a solution  but i don't know how to prove that it's the smallest.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you mean $\{a,b\}$, $\{c,d\}$ should be distinct? Otherwise, clearly, $a=b=c=d=1$.

Comment: Yes a,b,c,d should all be distinct and nonzero - edited the question

Comment: reminiscent of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Some ideas to reduce the problem to a finite number of cases to check:*

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $a<b$ and $c<d$ and that $a$ is the smallest number. Let $P=abcd$. Assume that $P<224$. Then $a^4<P<224$ so $a<\sqrt[4]{224}$ so $a\in\{1,2,3\}$

Moreover, $b>c$, since otherwise $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ wouldn't hold. Then the product $ac$ is smaller than $\sqrt{224}<15$ so $ac \in\{1,\dots,14\}$.

This leaves $(a,c)\in\{(1,2),(1,3),\dots,(1,14),(2,3),(2,4),\dots,(2,7),(3,4)\}$, that is $19$ possibilities.

For each of them, you can find $b$ and $d$ by solving $b^2-d^2=c^2-a^2$. Note that $b^2-d^2=(b-d)(b+d)$ and $c^2-a^2>0$, so $b>d$, $b-d<b+d$, and $b-d$ and $b+d$ are positive factors of $c^2-a^2$. This leads to a finite (and hopefully not too large) number of cases to check.

You can reduce a bit the number of cases to check by noticing that the system $b+d=q_1$ and $b-d=q_2$ (where $q_1q_2=c^2-a^2$) has an integer solution if and only if $q_1$ and $q_2$ are both even or both odd. So, the system has no solution if $c^2-a^2=2q$, where $q$ is odd.